# Tornar a key primária duplicável

Tags: mysql, sql

Ao inserir os dados na minha tabela SQL tudo ocorre normal.

Porém, ao tentar inserir pela segunda vez, com o mesmo valor em `id` que é o campo principal da tabela, ele retorna o seguinte erro:
`Duplcate entry '156' for key 'PRIMARY'`.

No entando, eu quero que meu sistema insira uma nova linha de dados que possua o mesmo ID. Como eu faço para tornar esse *primary key* 'duplicavel' ?

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `controledegm` (
  `char_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `char_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `item_quantidade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`char_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=150007 ;
```

Comment: Nesse caso você não precisa de Primary Key, o correto é você criar a tabela sem defini-la que tudo correrá bem.

Comment: E como eu crio sem definir ela?

Comment: Poste o sql que usou para criar a tabela.

Comment: editei no conteudo da pergunta

Comment: Você já tem a chave primaria como `AUTO_INCREMENT`. No insert não deve atribuir valor a ela. Poste o Insert/Update que está a dar o erro.

Comment: @ramaral ta mas no caso é só remover este AUTO_INCREMENT... No meu caso o único problema é que todas as minhas colunas pode vir a repetir o seu valor, e a key primary não pode ser repetida, então a questão é se tem como criar uma tabela sem essa key primária ou eu devo criar uma coluna somente para armazenar essa keyprimaria...

Comment: Editei a minha resposta.

Comment: @GGirotto: por definição uma chave primária é um campo cujo valor identifica univocamente cada linha de uma tabela, portanto não pode existir em sua tabela duas linhas com o mesmo valor para chave primária.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto não é possível assim, diretamente. A chave primária não pode conter duplicatas. Dependendo do sistema de banco de dados não pode sequer estar em qualquer ordem, mas não acho que seja o seu caso, mesmo você não informando qual está usando.

O que você pode fazer é tornar a chave primária única com algo além do `id`. Você não deu muitas informações de como está sua tabela mas poderia ter a chave primária `id+item`, por exemplo. Aí, mesmo que o `id` seja igual, a coluna `item` sendo diferente tornaria a chave única.

Em MySQL isto é feito com `PRIMARY KEY (char_id, item_id)` na definição da tabela.

Mas pense bem, porque o `id` deveria ser único, se ele não pode ser único, você deveria repensá-lo. Provavelmente está usando ele de forma inadequado, não está funcionando como um identificador, que pressupõe-se que seja único.

Mas como você tem uma coluna que dá toda pinta de ser única, afinal você até colocou até um `AUTO_INCREMENT` nela, seu problema deve ser outro. Você não quer colocar nada duplicado. Você quer apenas deixar o sistema criar o `id` para você.

```
INSERT INTO controledegm (char_id, char_name, etc) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'nome', etc)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/AutoIncrementDefault.sql).

Se realmente você precisa que este `char_id` se repita, então crie uma nova coluna para fazer este papel, e só nessa coluna você vai por o `AUTO_INCREMENT`, vai definir que ela é `PRIMARY KEY` e na hora de inserir vai usar o `DEFAULT` como valor de inserção.

Comment: E tem como criar uma tabela sem definir uma primary key?

Comment: Sim e não. É possível não definir, mas raramente você deveria fazer isto. No fundo a tabela terá uma chave primária que você não tem nenhum controle. E não sei se resolveria tudo o que você quer. Pode funcionar em um primeiro momento e depois você perceber que foi um erro.

Comment: Então seria interessante criar uma coluna só para armazenar essa primary key? Porque no caso todas as colunas dessa minha tabela podem vir a repetir o seu valor

Comment: Sim, é altamente interessante, mesmo que ela sirva só para isto. Mas pelo que eu vejo você já fez isto. O `char_id` já não é assim? Com o `AUTO_INCREMENT` em tese ela não vai repetir, a não ser que você tente manualmente, o que não é desejável também.

Comment: Entendido. Farei o mesmo então. Muito obrigado pelo suporte. Vou marcar usa resposta como a melhor devido aos comments. Abraço

Answer (score 5):

Um dos requisitos da *Primary key* é não permitir duplicados.
A sua função é identificar cada um dos registos(linhas) da tabela.
Por isso terá de ter valores únicos e não nulos.

Se é sua necessidade ter essa coluna com valores repetidos ela não pode ser *Primary key*.

Para evitar situações como essa é que é recomendado que a *Primary key* seja uma coluna independente dos dados e gerida pelo banco.
O seu valor é atribuído automaticamente pelo motor do banco.

No [MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) a forma de a declarar é:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    .....
    .....
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
 )
```

***EDIT*** <sub>- Na sequência dos comentários trocados na pergunta.</sub>

Se você tem necessidade de atribuir valores à coluna `char_id` não a defina como chave primária.
No entanto é recomendável que a tabela tenha uma.
Faça assim:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `controledegm` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `char_id` int(11) unsigned,
  `char_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `item_quantidade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=150007 ;
```

A coluna `char_id` passa a ser uma coluna normal e a tabela terá a chave primária na coluna `id`.

Answer (score -1):

É impossível realizar isso uma chave primaria não pode se repetir, basta remover  a propriedade AUTO_INCREMENT da coluna